# Did Barbarik see that in both sides only Krishna was present and all people fighting were Krishna only?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

Is it true that when Barbarik was asked what he saw in the Mahabharat war, he replied that in both sides every person was Krishna himself and the only person who was fighting was Krishna.

Is such a thing mentioned in Mahabharat ?

Answer (score 2):

Barbarik didnt say that he saw Krishna everywhere. Barbarik said that he saw a joint form of Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva ( Hari-Hara form) killing everyone in Kurukshetra.

1. Barbarik’s description of Lord Hari-Hara killing everyone at Kurukshetra -

> Barbarīka said: "One man was seen by me fighting with the enemies.
> **On the left side he had five faces** and **oṇ the right side he had only one** **face**. **On the left, he had ten hands holding
> **triden**t** and other weapons aloft; **on the right he had four hands holding discus** and other weapons aloft. **On the left he was
> having matted hair**; **On the right, a large crown**. **On the left
> side, he had smeared ash** and **on the right he had applied sandal
> paste.** On **the left he wore the moon and on the right there was the
> lustre of Kausthubha jewel**. On seeing him even I was frightened
> much. **Such a man and ṇo other person, who killed them (the enemies)
> was seen by me."**
>
> When this was said there was a shower of flowers of very great lustre
> from the sky. The divine musical instruments were sounded. They said,
> “Well done! Well done!” **The sons of Pāṇḍu became surprised. They
> bowed down to Puruṣottama.**

- Chapter 66, Kaumarika Khanda, Maheshwara Khanda, Skanda Purana.